# Python Programming on Inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a code where in I have a base class for `SchoolMember` and derived two classes : `Teacher` & `Student`. Please refer the code below:

```
class SchoolMember:
    '''Represents school member'''
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        print('Initialised school member is:', format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        print ('Name: \t Age: ', format(self.name, self.age))

class Teacher(SchoolMember):
    def __init__(self,name,salary,age):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self,name,age)
        self.salary=salary
        print ('Initialised teacher is ', format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        '''Prints the salary of the teacher'''
        print('Salary of teacher is ', format(self.salary))

class Student(SchoolMember):
    def __init__(self,name,age,fees):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self,name,age)
        self.fees=fees
        print('Initialised student is',format(self.name))

    def tell(self):
        '''Tells the fees of the student'''
        print('Fees  of student is', format(self.fees))

t = Teacher('Richa', 26,4000)
s = Student('Shubh',21, 2000)

print()
members = [t,s]
for member in members:
    member.tell()
```

Output :

```
('Initialised school member is:', 'Richa')
('Initialised teacher is ', 'Richa')
('Initialised school member is:', 'Shubh')
('Initialised student is', 'Shubh')
()
('Salary of teacher is ', '4000')
('Fees  of student is', '2000')
```

Now , my question is : how to get the age in output?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking.  Are you asking how to call the base-class version of tell or the format issue Martijn is answering, or some other issue?

Answer (score 1):

You want to read up on the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) documentation; you are not using it the way it was designed to; the function formats a value according to a specification (the optional second argument).

In fact, you do not need to use it *at all*.

Use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead, a method on strings:

```
print 'Name: {}\t Age: {}'.format(self.name, self.age)
```

Here the `{}` placeholders are replaced with the values you pass to the method.

Note that I didn't use `print` as a function; in Python 2 it is a *statement*; this is why you see `()` when you execute `print()`; that's just `print tuple()`, really. You *could* use `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your modules, but I'll stick with the old statement for now; it'd be better to just switch to Python 3 entirely.

Next, you want to execute the overridden `SchoolMember.tell()` method directly from your subclasses:

```
def tell(self):
    '''Tells the fees of the student'''
    SchoolMember.tell(self)
    print 'Fees  of student is {}'.format(self.fees)
```

Because you access the method *unbound* on the class, you need to manually pass in `self`.

In new-style classes (inheriting from `object`, the default base class in Python 3), you could also use the [`super()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super); if your tutorial is using `super()` *already* but you could not get it to work, you are most likely following a Python 3 tutorial and you want to upgrade, rather than stick with a legacy version of the language.